# Reloading Apache2 via Terminal in MAC OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache2

Am trying to reload Apache 2 via /init.d/apache2 reload command in terminal but I get a command not found error and when I look at the etc/ directory in Finder I can't see any init.d folder. Is there somewhere else this init.d folder might be?

Answer (score 12):

Just type in the terminal:

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

graceful reloads the configuration files and gracefully restarts. Any current connections are allowed to complete.

For more info on the apachectl command just type:

```
man apachectl
```

Answer (score 3):

And if that doesn't work, you can try `sudo apachectl restart`.  Just for reference, OS X doesn't use `init.d` (although it used to); it uses `launchd` instead.  See http://launchd.macosforge.org/.

Comment: THanks too. That was driving me mental.